# How to make the bg of a single legend transparent in a merged plot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend, scatter

I don't have to mention I am new, and my problem has too many solutions. I tried about 12 different versions and couldn't solve it:
The example given is close to my desired plot I want to generate.
I overtook a given script from 2013, so I do not entirely understand what to do to change it in the way I would like:

1. Plot 1's legend in the bottom right corner without a title, transparent background and instead of 1 and 2 the labels "urban" and "non-urban".I am aware that "legend.position="none"" delets all legends, but was not able to find a solution that looked like at least close to [this](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/figure/unnamed-chunk-12-3.png). Still it is not on the plot, not transparent and has a title.
2. Unfortunately somehow the dots changed into squares in this process and I have no clue why. I didn't change geom_point.
3. Another flaw I want to change is to remove the top line over the central plot. But how?
4. And last but not least I am not sure if the function geom.mooth(method=lm) does reflect the regression line + confidence interval, because the description says it adds a conditional mean which is, afaIk, not the same. Is my concern unnecessary?

Edit: shorter Version plot1 out of 3 merged plots:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(42)
DF <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100,mean=c(1,5)),y=rlnorm(100,meanlog=c(8,6)),group=1:2)

p1 <- ggplot(DF,aes(x=x,y=y,colour=factor(group))) + geom_point(shape=16) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0.02,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0.02,0)) +
  geom_rug() +
  geom_smooth(method=lm,alpha=0.3) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position=c(0.9,0.09),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0),
        "points"))
```

Thanks for any advice, I am researching on this topic since 2 weeks, even though I thought I am studying psychology, I learned a lot ... but not enough in the short time to success. :/

Comment: You have a lot of questions, and a very complicated plot. Try building it from scratch, and you'll probably end up happier (and learn more). As far as the legend, it's coming from `colour=factor(group)` in `p1`. The best way to change its levels is to update `group` as the factor you want when you assemble your data, and pass that to `colour`. The location of the legend is set by `legend.position=c(0.9,0.15)`; chop it out and it reverts outside the plot, which looks silly once you assemble all three. `legend.position=c(0.9,0.85)` or so looks better.

Comment: Break it up into a several smaller questions, each with a small example. You will learn a lot, and we will find them easier to answer. And make up some random data for it too.

Comment: I found a solution for #1:
`library(scales)
labels=c("Urban","Rural")`
Then in theme `...,legend.title=element_blank(),legend.background=element_rect(fill=alpha(0.1)),...`

For #2 it might be a bug of the loaded libraries, cause even addressing shape=16 doesn't make the dots round like a circle (neither any full circles).

For #3 Difficult to address without the full code: Is it possible to remove just single frame parts (cause the right frame disappeared after merging).

For #4 Well, most related blogs use geom_smooth for 95% confidence interval. Still I have a definition problem here.